# Finding minimums in specified intervals for time series data

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate, outliers

I have a set of lab values I want to trend over time in relation to a date of hospital admission. Each patient had variable entry's for this lab/follow up time. My goal is to identify the minimum value of this lab at various time intervals after their admission (date_one in the df) ie day 0-30, day 31-90, 1-2 years, 2-3, 3-4 etc, until their last follow up, in order to help me identity outliers that are a certain threshold above their baseline. As this lab value can change naturally over time I want to find these minimums to establish new baselines. As each patient has variable follow up, some up to 20 years, I was having trouble finding a function to find the local minimums that wasn't using filtering and mutate to make a new column for every interval I desired. My dput output is below, if this is incorrect formatting please let me know!

```r
structure(list(lab_date = structure(c(10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 
10010, 10011, 10012, 10013, 10014, 10015, 10016, 10018, 10019, 
10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 10025, 10026, 10099, 10225, 
10242, 10361, 10575, 10729, 10785, 10849, 10856, 10857, 10858, 
10859, 10872, 10975, 11071, 11151, 11179, 11197, 11198, 11199, 
11201, 11202, 11203, 11204, 11206, 11207, 11208, 11210, 11226, 
11228, 11229, 11230, 11254, 11256, 11257, 11258, 11270, 11281, 
11282, 11282, 11309, 11310, 11338, 11339, 11372, 11373, 11401, 
11499, 11536, 11564, 11582, 11597, 11598, 11625, 11660, 11663, 
11664, 11665, 11666, 11667, 11668, 11695, 11696, 11697, 11698, 
11699, 11700, 11701, 11723, 11729, 11730, 11731, 11732, 11733, 
11734, 11735, 11736, 11737, 11765, 11828), class = "Date"), lab_value = c(1.1, 
1, 1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 2.4, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 
1.2, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1, 
2.1, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.6, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 
2.1, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.8, 2.1, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.1, 2.1, 
2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2, 2, 2.1, 2, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.2, 2.2, 
2.1, 1.9, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 
3.6, 3.3, 3.1, 3), ID = c(182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
182, 182), Date_One = structure(c(10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    ID = 182, .rows = structure(list(1:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible option with `tidyverse` (but I'm not sure what format you want the output to be):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date_One) %>% 
  mutate(years = as.numeric(difftime(Date_One,lab_date,units = "days")/365)) %>% 
  filter(years >= 0) %>% 
  group_by(gr=cut(years, breaks= c(-Inf, c((30/365), (60/365)), seq(1, 20, by = 1))), ID) %>% 
  summarise(lab_value = min(lab_value))
```

**Output**

```
  gr               ID lab_value
  <fct>         <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (-Inf,0.0822]   182       1.2
2 (0.164,1]       182       1.2
3 (1,2]           182       1.2
4 (2,3]           182       1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It has you specify the different segment breaks as days (can easily convert this to months or something else but will have to change other code), then for each of these segments, isolates the rows that are within the range of those breaks, and then finds the minimum of those. If there are no values in those dates it will return an NA.
This should work for your data provided, if you want to apply this over a data frame with multiple ids let me know, that should just be an extra little loop.

```
#Convert object to dataframe
Data=data.frame(structure(list(lab_date = structure(c(10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 
                                                      10010, 10011, 10012, 10013, 10014, 10015, 10016, 10018, 10019, 
                                                      10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 10025, 10026, 10099, 10225, 
                                                      10242, 10361, 10575, 10729, 10785, 10849, 10856, 10857, 10858, 
                                                      10859, 10872, 10975, 11071, 11151, 11179, 11197, 11198, 11199, 
                                                      11201, 11202, 11203, 11204, 11206, 11207, 11208, 11210, 11226, 
                                                      11228, 11229, 11230, 11254, 11256, 11257, 11258, 11270, 11281, 
                                                      11282, 11282, 11309, 11310, 11338, 11339, 11372, 11373, 11401, 
                                                      11499, 11536, 11564, 11582, 11597, 11598, 11625, 11660, 11663, 
                                                      11664, 11665, 11666, 11667, 11668, 11695, 11696, 11697, 11698, 
                                                      11699, 11700, 11701, 11723, 11729, 11730, 11731, 11732, 11733, 
                                                      11734, 11735, 11736, 11737, 11765, 11828), class = "Date"), lab_value = c(1.1, 
                                                                                                                                1, 1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 2.4, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.1, 
                                                                                                                                1.1, 1.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 
                                                                                                                                1.2, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1, 
                                                                                                                                2.1, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.6, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 
                                                                                                                                2.1, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.8, 2.1, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.1, 2.1, 
                                                                                                                                2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2, 2, 2.1, 2, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.2, 2.2, 
                                                                                                                                2.1, 1.9, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 
                                                                                                                                3.6, 3.3, 3.1, 3), ID = c(182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 
                                                                                                                                                          182, 182), Date_One = structure(c(10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856, 10856), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ID = 182, .rows = structure(list(1:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE)))
#Define Segment Breaks in days
SegmentBreaks=c(0,30,90,365,730)

#Function for finding min date

MinAtSegments=function(Data,SegmentBreaks){
  IDNumber=length(unique(Data$ID))
  UniqueIDs=unique(Data$ID)
  OutputLength=length(SegmentBreaks)
  
  Date1=min(Data$lab_date)
  
  DateBreaks=Date1+SegmentBreaks
  
  Output=matrix(NA,nrow=IDNumber,ncol=length(SegmentBreaks))
  
  DateBreaks=c(DateBreaks,Sys.Date())
  for(j in 1:IDNumber){
    DataID=Data[Data$ID==UniqueIDs[j],]
  for(i in 1:length(Output)){
    LabVals=Data$lab_value[Data$lab_date>=DateBreaks[i] & Data$lab_date<DateBreaks[i+1]]
    Output[j,i]=ifelse(length(LabVals)>0,min(LabVals),NA)
  }
  }

  Output=data.frame('ID'=UniqueIDs,'MinVals'=Output)
  return(Output)
}

#Run Function
MinAtSegments(Data,SegmentBreaks)
```

Comment: For a bit of extra detail explaining some of the weird extra lines, it automatically makes the last day range you put in (in my example 360 days or 2 years) capture everything from that range up until the current date, so it is essentially anything greater than 730. Also the way the comparisons are currently set up is that it takes anything greater than or equal to the lower date range, and anything less than but not equal to the higher range. So effectively in my example our brackets are 0-29 days, 30-89 days, 90-364 days, and so on. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey I think this is exactly what I was looking for! I would want to apply over multiple IDs

Comment: Great, I think this should now work for multiple IDs (I added a sub loop into the function, so essentially this just does the same thing it did previously to each subset of the dataframe by ID. Let me know if this works for you or if you have any other questions about the code. The output is a data frame with one row per ID, where the column values are the minimum values for the breaks you would define. The first value would be between the first 2 segment breaks, second column value would be between breaks 2 and 3, and so on.